# Using mixer grinder circuit breaker in a electronic circuit

Tags: lipo, fuses, circuit-protection

I'm thinking of using a 5A mixer grinder circuit breaker in an electronic circuit which uses a 2200mAh Li-Po battery and a 5A step-down voltage regulator. Is it safe to use such a circuit breaker in this application or should I go with a normal panel mounted fuse? Is there anything I should consider?

Comment: What is a "mixer grinder circuit breaker"?

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/search?q=mixer+grinder+circuit+breaker&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&rls=%7Bmoz:distributionID%7D:%7Bmoz:locale%7D:%7Bmoz:official%7D&tbm=isch&gws_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=TfELWpelN4novASvsLSgBA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most switching regulators (I assume it is switching given the 5A rating) have built-in over current protection.  This can be foldback current regulation where the voltage is reduced until the current drops to 5A, or hiccup where the output is switched off when the over-current condition is detected and then possibly gradually turned back on (via the slow-start ramp) after a timeout.  If the over-current condition still exists, then the hiccup cycle is repeated.

The circuit breaker would almost certainly work, but you may not know what the trip current is for the breaker (5A is probably the hold current where it will not trip), and you don't know how quickly the circuit breaker will activate on an over current condition.  If the step-down converter is limited to 5A, the circuit breaker is unlikely to every trip (it might on a short circuit as the energy in the output capacitor of the step-down converter is dumped but probably not).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I think I should go with the fuse.

Comment: Be aware that fuses can disconnect the circuit very suddenly (fast dV/dT).  Depending on the input circuitry on your device, this fast disconnection can create a high voltage pulse (many times the power supply voltage) that can damage or destroy the device you are powering.  Circuit breakers can have the same problem.  A small snubber capacitor between ground and the output of the fuse/breaker can reduce the problem.

Comment: I'm using the fuse before a voltage regulator. Battery voltage 7.4v and maximum input voltage of the regulator is 30v. Still does that spike would cause damage? Anyway I will add a capacitor as you said. Thank you so much for the info.